# How to properly integrate google spreadsheets with highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, google-sheets

I am having zero luck creating a data viz with highcharts using google spreadsheets. I've spent most of the day goggling for help and reading through google API / highcharts documentation / stack overflow / etc, and I'm still at the same spot I started this morning.

It seems to be an issue relating to new vs. old google spreadsheets. For example, I found  [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgAlL) example to work, but as you'll see, the google spreadsheet has the older URL construction that includes "key=". When I update with a key from a new spreadsheet (one that does not have the URL construction with "key="), the chart isn't created.

Any ideas? My sheets are all public and published to the web, so I know that's not it.

Here's the spreadsheet I've been testing with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18jFq7JiZI4wfj0SOMZh3fii1lquGF7NWJnmoFsXNJbM/edit?usp=sharing, using the key 18jFq7JiZI4wfj0SOMZh3fii1lquGF7NWJnmoFsXNJbM

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you point Highcharts at your key, you get an [error 14](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14).  Looking at your sheet, it chokes on the second row "Total" since those numbers are formatted as strings.  Fixing that in the sheet, and [tweaking some of the parameters](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/rambera/js/modules/data.src.js) you can pass to Highcharts and your chart will [start to take shape](http://jsfiddle.net/PhJqL/):

```
data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '18jFq7JiZI4wfj0SOMZh3fii1lquGF7NWJnmoFsXNJbM',
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 5,
    startRow: 0
},
```

Hopefully, that'll get you going, your chart still needs a bit more work (too many xAxis labels, the total column overwhelms the rest of the data, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, Mark! This gives me a lot of good stuff to dig into. Thanks for including the documentation (and stopping me from more head::desk over this).