# Google spreadsheet sharing

Tags: highcharts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to generate charts using Google Spreadsheets as datasource.

Highcharts has the following demo which works just fine:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts data from Google Spreadsheets'
        },

        data: {
            googleSpreadsheetKey: '0AoIaUO7wH1HwdENPcGVEVkxfUDJkMmFBcXMzOVVPdHc'
        }

    });
```

However, when I try to use my own spreadsheet there seems to be a problem.

I can only assume that I must be missing something regarding the sharing of the file.

Here is the file im trying to use:
( I have the spreadsheet sharing set up so that anyone with the link can see it.)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2vBhvmAmdrKt1xHNlCXehV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0

Here is a fiddle where I first load the demo-file and then (fail) to load my own file.
http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/5y6onf3y/

Have someone encountered similar problem and might have a solution?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The suggested solution is loading the data the same way as I am currently doing it. By using the key.
I have 2 identical sheets. The only differences ( that im aware of ) is that one is shared from my google account and the other one from someone elses.

Comment: I am able to load without issue. Can you load the jsFiddle or does it not load on a local web page? You don't appear to actually be loading a spreadsheet - just including the key.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Are you saying that when you use the fiddle, you get two charts loaded?
In my case only the first one loads. You say that I only seem to be including the key and not loading the sheet. From what I understand thats the way itś supposed to be done:
Here is a demo from Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/google-spreadsheet/

Comment: You are missing the `http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetWorksheet` value. Only one chart loads - because you are not loading the Google sheet - just providing the key. You need both (if you have a specific worksheet).

Comment: You are loading the sheet, my mistake. You should only have one chart - which you do. The chart loaded is the default demo chart.

Comment: Actually im expecting two charts. The first one is the demo and the second ( which is not appearing) should be https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2vBhvmAmdrKt1xHNlCXehV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly integrate google spreadsheets with highcharts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436425/how-to-properly-integrate-google-spreadsheets-with-highcharts)

Comment: You are not loading the spreadsheet you think you are - no where is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2vBhvmAmdrKt1xHNlCXehV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0 listed in your code on that jsfiddle.

Comment: Did you publish it? Except sharing it, you have to publish it on the internet (File -> Publish...)

Comment: @morganfree Thank you!
I did not realize that sharing was not enough. After publishing, it works as expected. If you want to make an answer of your comment iĺl accept it.

Comment: Great, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the spreadsheet available for Highcharts it is required to publish it to the web, so the callback script can be executed.

*File -> Publish to the web...*

[image: publishing spreadsheet]